# Why does my 2 way data binding in my directive not work?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a directive that will render a table. Its main "parameters" are the table headers and the data, which i am passing as attributes from the controller. The problem is some of my data won't pass into my directive, even though i use 2 way data binding. This is the code:

ze directive:

```
Application.directive('ngDataTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        templateUrl : '/templates/directives/datatable.html',
        scope : {
            headers : '=',
            dataMatrix : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        }
    }
});
```

ze directive template (datatable.html):

```
<div class="table-wrapper">

    <table class="default hover sticky">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="header in headers"> <% header %> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <% dataMatrix %>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

ze controller:

```
Application.controller('CycleCountingLogsController', ['$http', '$scope', 'initData', function( $http, $scope, initData){

.... some code

logs.tableHeaders = [
        'Name', 'Product Id', 'Building Quantity', 'Post Quantity', 'Picked Quantity', 'Qty. on Orders', 'Quantity Change', 'Ov. Found', 'Ov. Included', 'Ch. Found', 'Ch. Included', 'Created At'
    ];

    logs.dataMatrix = initData.data.logs;  // initData is a service that fetches data by AJAX for each view that needs initial data, and logs is a matrix (table rows, cell values)

....
```

and ze html declaration of the directive:

```
<ng-data-table headers="logs.tableHeaders" data-matrix="logs.dataMatrix"></ng-data-table>
```

The headers show up, but the matrix data doesn't. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, it was a typo, all is good folks